# How to name base css classes so that other user can easily relate

Tags: css, plugins

I am creating a plug and play html application. I have defined a base css class. But when other users integrate this html page in their application, they need to override these classes to match look and feel of their application.

What can I do here to make it convenient for other users to understand which class is uses for which component. Does it help if I arrange classes in order of there usage in the application. is there any other best practice I can follow here. Does adding lot of comments helps?

Answer (score 0):

Comments would be the best way to go here. Also you might want to have a separate file/website with documentation that explains the logic behind the code (With examples). That's what most developers would do.